# Fourier transform analysis with Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I was using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30209779/fourier-transform-in-python) post as a guide on determining the dominating frequencies given some discrete data set.

One of the solutions was posted as follows:

```
x = np.linspace(0,5,100)
y = np.sin(2*np.pi*x)

## fourier transform
f = np.fft.fft(y)
## sample frequencies
freq = np.fft.fftfreq(len(y), d=x[1]-x[0])
plt.plot(freq, abs(f)**2) ## will show a peak at a frequency of 1 as it should.
```

This worked for me but I tried increasing the frequency from 1 hz to 100 hz, and I get some bizarre plots that don't reflect anything. I also tried adding another wave of frequency 5 hz in it, and I didn't get the result that I would expect.

My question is how do I go about fixing this? I've tried reading documentation on this, but I'm still confused on what is actually going on. From what I understand, the fft.fft(y) takes the fourier transform while the fft.fftfreq makes frequencies? Why does it take the length as a parameter? And what exactly is the role of d? Finally, why do we plot abs(f)**2?

Comment: Too many questions at once for SO format unfortunately. E.g. abs(f)**2 is the intensity of the signal at that frequency (I think, and likely I'm not using the right terms), but no one searching for that answer would find it here.

Comment: Pick one of the figures that isn't the result you expect and include both that version of the code and the figure produced. `fft` returns the fast Fourier transform and `fftfreq` returns the corresponding frequencies. `d` is a parameter used in the `fftfreq` function; see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fft.fftfreq.html#numpy.fft.fftfreq

Comment: +1 bc I'm a physicist turned programmer and Fourier transforms are friggin awesome. x space, momentum space, meh just use a fourier...

Comment: and my guess on taking the abs(f)**2 is bc what you're getting is a probability density

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing - you should restrict frequencies to less than N/2 where N is the fft length